# Is there any difference in strtotime +day or +days?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Was googling this, but couldn't find the answer. Was wondering, if there is a difference in these two scripts?

+3 **day**:

```
echo date( 'd.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime( '+3 day' ) );
```

+3 **days**:

```
echo date( 'd.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime( '+3 days' ) );
```

The output is exactly the same.

So is that implemented to make sure people get less errors or what?
And witch one should be preferred to use?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is basically same thing, and for usability and *pretty* purposes:

```
strtotime( '+1 day' );
strtotime( '+3 day' );
strtotime( '+1 days' );
strtotime( '+3 days' );
strtotime( '+1 weeks' );
strtotime( '+3 week' );
```

You can use the one you like more, basically the one that defines de number, `1 day`, `3 days`

Comment: I understand that they are for *easy* purpose uses only, but why isn't there one standard but multiple options?

Comment: Because of the user. And PHP is not a strict language.